# HTML Table - styling individual many thousands of cells

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

In the process of making a html versions of an app, and one part is a table which can end up having many many cells.

Around: 150 columns, with easily up to 10,000 rows.

Question is performance, and what would be decent why to be able to style each cell based on content?

So in each cell is a number, and the background color filled in based on the percentage that number fits in.

For example: have banding

```
77-100 = red
33 - 77 = blue
0 < 33 = green
0 = black
```

What I have tried on a small table is giving the class to each `<td>` that I would want to color it.
(colors being user changeable, so setting a class, should be able to change class definition)

So get something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class='percentile-100'>87.5%</td>
  <td class='percentile-77'>75.0%</td>
  <td class='percentile-0'>0.0%</td>
```

and in CSS, set style for classes. Only 4 styles needed.

Now with (150 * 10,000 = ) 1,500,000 cells to be styled, I'm thinking what impact might be like.

Table being generated from JavaScript with data. But yeah data in the MB area.
Table then rendered client side. So as rendering, decides what class value to set.

What other possible ways to style each cell based on content?

Comment: Even with 1.5M cells, you are still talking about 101 percentile classes.  I personally think this would be better than 1.5M in-line styled background colors.

Comment: I'd suggest assigning the classes server-side, rather than handing that task off to potentially mobile devices with relatively small amounts of RAM (I'd hate to see what that would do to my iPad Air, with a mere 1gb, for example. And bear in mind that the UI of any table with 10000 rows is (likely to be) painful.

Comment: Actually, inline styles will render faster on the browser with less load than using classes. But it still seems like a really horrible user interface (unless your just trying to put blocks of colour on a screen, in which case you should be using a canvas or server generated image)

Comment: How are the table cells generated? If you have control over the generation code, you can simply apply the class to the elements based on the percentage when the cells are generated. Two birds with one stone.

Comment: If possible, only work with the cells which are visible. Putting a few MB of data into memory isn't a big deal for a browser; generating a DOM with a million+ elements from it is a *huge* task (anecdotally, tablets will start to struggle when you have roughly 50K cells). I'd suggest lazy-generation of rows from the data. You'll then be dealing with a few thousand cells at a time, which will allow you to use whatever style approach is convenient. Also, look use the browser's tools to show you where the time is spent (e.g. IE 11 has a very nice breakdown of time taken to calculate, paint, etc.)

Comment: I will update my question above shortly. but rfornal comment not correct, there would only be 4 classes in the description i wrote, see section on the bandings. it more that there would be 1.5 million td elements that have a class that needs looking up.

Comment: @symcbean this is a good point, the style of report might be simplified, and use some simply canvas to represent the information.

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that you're loading 10,000 rows - nobody is going to view that much content at one time. Why not load 500 at a time with ajax as the user scrolls? It'd help make it look faster, even if it isn't necessarily.

Comment: @DACrosby im going take this approach, reduce load, screen cant show more then handful of rows anyhow, so load "reasonable" amount with scroll load more.

can you make an answer of that so can accept answer - or is there way to make comment the answer?

Comment: Maze, I made it as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is not loading so many rows at one time. I made a program a while back that compared thousands of data points and it loaded horribly slow - the problem was that I was displaying all of the individual results. It was nice in the end, but we only needed to see the totals. I ended up displaying only the totals and making an ajax call to re-get the individual results as needed if someone was looking for them specifically.

In short, if you're worried it'll take to long to style all of the cells, you should probably not load so many at once. May want to look into [AJAX pagination](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/).